# Number of template arguments in templated constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

For a (possibly non templated) class I can have a templated constructor :

```
struct A {
    template<class T> A(T const& arg) {}
}
```

Is the number of template arguments limited by the number of arguments that can be deduced ? If so what's the related Standard quote?

For example if the constructor was

```
template<class T1, class T2> A(T2 const& arg) {}
```

this call would cause a compile error

```
A<int>(double()); // creation of a temporary
```

or how would I call the constructor ? This also fails :

```
A::A<int>(double()); // creation of a temporary
```

Comment: "how would I call the constructor" - not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you can't pass the types using *template-argument-list* syntax doesn't necessarily mean you can't pass the list of types for templated constructor at all:

```
template <typename...>
struct _ {};

struct A
{
    template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
    A(_<T1, T2, T3>) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a{_<int, double, char>{}};
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61a6dc2e1e472f55)

Comment: Is there any proposal of language support for specifying *template-argument-list* for templated constructor?

Answer (score 6):

There is a note in the standard, that you cannot use explicit template arguments in constructor:

> [ Note: Because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name,
>   and because conversion member function templates and constructor member function templates are called
>   without using a function name, there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these
>   function templates. —end note ]

Source: `14.5.2 Member templates` from N3337 draft.

But of course you can have more constructor template parameters than constructor arguments - as long as they can be deduced from constructor arguments:

Example:

```
struct A {
    template<class T, int N> A(T (&arg)[N]) {}
};
```

Comment: As long as they can be deduced from constructor arguments or (other / default) template arguments.